# error while installing virualbox

Tags: virtualbox

Popup this error window while installing virtual box shown in the image, please help me to install the virtual box.

Comment: CD/DVD "Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS_Trusty Tahr_ -Release i386(20150218.1)" is required                                                                                                                                                  Getting this error

Comment: You did not specify any image link...

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to install VirtualBox? apt-get or dpkg ?You can download VirtualBox [i386](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.28/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.28-100309%7EUbuntu%7Eraring_i386.deb) or [amd64](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.28/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.28-100309%7EUbuntu%7Eraring_amd64.deb) from the links.

And then run the below command,

sudo dpkg --install virtualbox-4.3*.deb

See if that helps.

Comment: i was trying to install it by apt-get,  got the solution. Any Way thank you so much to respond my question.